# Hibernate dont save objects if run in task executor

Tags: hibernate

```
//Hibernate dont save objects
public Response foo() {
    Runnable task = () -> runSavingProcessProcess();
    taskExecutor.execute(task);
    var response = new Response();
    response.setModel("stbe");
    return response;
}

//Work ok
public Response foo() {
    return runSavingProcessProcess();
}
```

I run saving process
and expect that process will be execute in different threads, but hibernate dont save objects.

Comment: Do.Not.Reuse.Persistence.Contexts.Across.Different.Threads